MS Teams chat response using graph API not working
I am using graph API to send an adaptive card message in teams chat, the expectation is for end user to fill in the date and submit. but hitting the submit button gives That action isn't supported here.
const axios = require("axios");

async function createChat(accessToken, senderId, recipientUserId) {
  const graphUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats";

  const chatPayload = {
    chatType: "oneOnOne",
    members: [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        roles: ["owner"],
        "user@odata.bind": `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${senderId}`,
      },
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        roles: ["owner"],
        "user@odata.bind": `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${recipientUserId}`,
      },
    ],
  };

  const response = await axios.post(graphUrl, chatPayload, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  return response.data.id; // chatId
}
async function sendAdaptiveCard(accessToken, chatId) {
  const graphUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/${chatId}/messages`;

  const adaptiveCard = {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.3",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Please select a date"
      },
      {
        "type": "Input.Date",
        "id": "selectedDate",
        "placeholder": "Enter your date"
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Submit",
        "data":{
            "msteams":{
                  "type":"messageBack",
                  "displayText":"Cards related queries"
              },
              "value":"selectedDate"
         }
      }
    ]
  };
  
  const message = {
    "body": {
      "contentType": "html",
      "content": `<attachment id="1"></attachment>`
    },
    "replyToId": "myemail@mydomain.com",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "contentUrl": "",
        "content": JSON.stringify(adaptiveCard),
        "name": null,
        "thumbnailUrl": null
      }
    ]
  };

 let reply= await axios.post(graphUrl, message, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  console.log(" ~ sendAdaptiveCard ~ reply:", reply.data.id)
  
}

(async () => {
  const accessToken = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN;
  const chatId = await createChat(
    accessToken,
    "<senderTokenHere>",
    "<receiverTokenHere>"
  );
  await sendAdaptiveCard(accessToken, chatId);
})();

Any help please

This is by design, please note that Microsoft Graph supports only OpenUrl card action. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples:~:text=Microsoft%20Graph%20supports%20the%20OpenUrl%20card%20action.%20Bots%20are%20required%20for%20other%20card%20actions.
